# Prevent a fullpage scrolling while scrolling a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to prevent the page from scrolling to the previous page while scrolling in a div element. Right now I'm using Alvarotrigo's fullpage scroll, not sure if this is relevant. 
Basically, there is 2 "page" in this page. ".table-responsive" is on the 2nd page and i've set it to be overflow:scroll. When scrolling up in that div, it also scrolls up to the 1st page.

I've tried this but this doesn't work:

```
$('.table-responsive').on( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) { 

var e0 = e.originalEvent;
var delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
e.preventDefault();  
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <div class="table">
      <thead>TABLE</thead>
      <tbody>...</tbody>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table-responsive {
width: 70%;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 40vh;
overflow: scroll;
border: 3px solid #fff;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
}
```

Comment: simply make overflow hidden to body element. works for my modals fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.table-responsive').on('mouseover', function(){
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}).on('mouseout', function(){
  $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```

think this is what you are looking for

Comment: this is not what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
.table-responsive {
max-width: 70%;
}
or
.table-responsive {
max-width: 250px;
}
```